# jquery toggle class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap as my css framework. I want to be able to toggle a class on that navbar once the user has scrolled past the big header image at the top of the website.

EDIT:

I went full derp... so I drank some more coffee and figured this out. Now if it's the best way to do it, not sure but here is what I have, and it works..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(".navbar").offset().top + $(".navbar").outerHeight(true) > $('.landing-header').outerHeight(true)) {
        $(".navbar").addClass("darker-bg");
    } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("darker-bg");
    }

});
```

@SetSailMedia also answered it so I went with their answer, which was cleaner than my imo

Comment: What is `$(this)`, in context? Incidentally, if you can show enough cod to reproduce the problem then you have more chance of receiving a useful answer (instead of guesses), and not having your question closed as 'off-topic' (for not including sufficient code to reproduce the problem). Please see the "[mcve]" guidelines for a better explanation.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm going to edit my post, one sec

Comment: try:     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.landing-header').offset().bottom) {
    $(".navbar").addClass("darker-bg");
}else{
    $(".navbar").addClass("darker-bg");
}

Comment: in context, `this` clearly is undefined.

Comment: @Pamblam `this` is 'rarely' undefined unless you set it explicitely

Comment: i can't think of any value that `this` could have that would cause such an error message other than undefined.

Comment: @Pamblam `window/document` would  https://jsfiddle.net/x0tz2use/

Comment: Guys, I updated my question with a solution I figured out, now not sure if it's good or not.

Comment: @BrandonStewart What??? Don't completly change your question! Some guys tried to answer your previous question, making then their answers completly unreleavnt now.

Comment: @BrandonStewart that update looks remarkably similar to my answer below... :/

Comment: @BrandonStewart I found [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/12/) somewhere, this should fix your problem, also put "1" if you want to toggle class when scroll form the top.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Ya that's ridiculous imho... +1 for your answer btw

Comment: Op, don't be obnoxious. mark the answer that was given to you don't just take credit for it.

Comment: Yeah awks.. Totally didn't see @SetSailMedia's answer at first. I ended up using their answer over what I got anyways since it looks more clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to measure is to compare `$(this).scrollTop` during `$(window).scroll()` event.

```
$(window).scroll( function( e ){ 
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > $('.landing-header').offset().top ){
        $(".navbar").addClass("darker-bg");
    } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("darker-bg");
    }
});
```

Forgive me, first post of this answer kept your original `.offset().bottom` property, which does not exist. I've updated to `.offset().top`. If you wanted to measure against bottom of the element, replace that line with:

```
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > ($('.landing-header').offset().top + $('.landing-header').outerHeight()) ){
```

Comment: There you should use `$(this).scrollTop()`

Comment: Yeah I eventually fixed it, your's looks more clean so I used yours in the end :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle class when scroll somewhere with something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 1) {
    $(".header").addClass("change");
} else {
    $(".header").removeClass("change");
}
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq05nme1/).